# Legacy SOAP web service - need a new client

Tags: java, ssl, soap, cxf, apache-axis

I have a legacy `SOAP` based web service, written using `Apache Axis2`. And the current client is created using plain old `JAVA Sockets` and `HTTP 1.0`.Planning to upgrade the client to use `HTTP 2.0`. What are the options based on the latest industry standards and best practices? The service url supports `SSL` as well.

1. Use Apache CXF client
2. Use Apache Axis client
3. HttpClient/ Httpurlconnection or something else?

Comment: are you using spring already in your application? if not I would ask you to first go through this https://dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-vs-apache-axis-vs and see if you figure out your need.

Comment: @SantosshKumhar - Yes I do have Spring. But I don't plan on rewriting the server side code, but merely the client side implementation with minimal code change.